# how to get tagged tweets data in twitter API?

Tags: api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to access the Twitter API via Python and get the tagged tweets data, but there are no documentation available in Twitter API.is there any possible way to get that data ?

Comment: do you mean the tweets that people tag your bot?

Comment: the documentation is at https://developer.twitter.com

Comment: No. tag my id in their photos.